# Saving output of a system call in perl to a text file

Tags: perl, date, foreach, text-files

Im trying to make this script put the output files in results/ but i only get them in results/spool. How can I make them end up in the right place?

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

use POSIX;
my $date = strftime "%Y%m%d_%H%M.txt", localtime;

my @files = <spool/*.*>;
foreach $file (@files) {
    my $date_file = $file;
    system("$^X  wfreq.pl $file >> results/${date_file}_$date");
    unlink("$file");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tested this ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use POSIX;
my $date = strftime "%Y%m%d_%H%M.txt", localtime;

my @files = <spool/*.*>;
foreach $file (@files) {
    (my $date_file = $file) =~ s!.*/!!;
    system("$^X  wfreq.pl $file >> results/${date_file}_$date");
    unlink("$file");
}
```

The functions `system()`, `qx()` & `exec()` can handle variables without any problems.

Comment: Yeah! I can't believe I was that close.. worked out perfect with the file writing, but i can't seem to get the date thing right. I want the filename to be in this format 20121025_1215.txt

Comment: Sweet, exactly like i wanted :) Super helpful!

Comment: I just realized something.. If i have two textfiles at the same time in "spool" the script puts the results in the same textfile output....how can i make a different result file for each file in spool?

Comment: You can do this by prefixing or suffixing the $date_file with the filename by example

Comment: Allright, well...uhm im not sure if I know how to do that. Would you mind showing me?  :) Im super-new to this whole thing.

Comment: It doesnt work for me, it gives me this back:  Can't declare scalar assignment in "my" at ./project.pl line 8, near ") =~"
Execution of ./project.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: The `my` wasn't at the good place. post edited with working code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for?

This will give you a separate file for each date

```
@files = <spool/*.*>;
foreach $file (@files) {
    system($^X, "wfreq.pl", $file);
    $DATE = strftime "%Y%m%d";
    open OUTPUT, '>results/$DATE.txt' or die;
    print OUTPUT $DATE;
}
```

Or for a file with results all in one text file

```
@files = <spool/*.*>;
open OUTPUT, '>>results/results.txt' or die;
foreach $file (@files) {
    system($^X, "wfreq.pl", $file);
    $DATE = strftime "%Y%m%d";
    print OUTPUT $DATE;
}
```